# Carthagenet token faucet

Tags: faucet, carthagenet, tokens

Are there any faucets that hand out any Fa1.2 or Fa2 tokens on the Carthage testnet?

I googled this and was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there aren't any. What you can do is copy the code of the token that interests you on Mainnet, deploy it on Carthagenet and create some tokens you can then use for your tests :)

Comment: I am unsure if I should accept this as a correct answer since someone might someday make such a faucet :)

Comment: That someone might be me :D I actually looked into how to do it since your question, it would be pretty easy to do it for USDtz but a lot more difficult for tzBTC (because the code is more complex). As of today, this is the correct answer, there is no faucet on Carthagenet for FA1.2 or FA2 tokens.

Comment: Didn't you build a faucet now? Time to update the answer? :)

Comment: I did but I am actually building a better one at the moment that will include both FA1.2 and FA2 tokens, I will update the answer with a link once it is ready :)

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: It's 99% done but there is a little bug in Taquito that prevents the token faucet from creating batches of transactions with the new Wallet API to mint multiple NFTs at the same time. I was waiting for an update on that but I forgot about it, thank you for reminding me, I am getting back to it!